# Remembering logged in status with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, session

I'm fairly new to PHP and have set up a login system that works but generates an error when I try and display a username on the main page.
My login code is:

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        // Verification success! User has logged-in!
        // Create sessions, so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        
        header('Location: mainpage.php');
}
```

and the recall on the mainpage.php is:

```
<?php
// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Then to display the username I have included:

```
<p>Welcome back, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>!</p>
```

I receive an error when this happens

> Warning: Undefined array key "name" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\refinery\mainpage.php on line 44

Comment: So `$_SESSION['loggedin']` must have _been_ set then, otherwise your code should not have been able to proceed to line 44, because of the `exit` statement.

Comment: isset may not be the best solution, because it would also work when `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;`.

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in first code block too?

Comment: I do. The system logs in, but cannot retain the username

Comment: add session_start() in first line of index.php

Comment: Thanks, I do have it at the beginning. Login works fine, I just can't retain the username for some reason.

Comment: Do some debugging. On mainpage.php, after the `session_start()` command, put `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what the session actualy contains at that moment. I assume that the `<p>Welcome back, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>!</p>` code is _after_ the `session_start()` command?

Comment: _Side note:_ "they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server" - By default, PHP actually does use cookies to send the session id to the client. The client then sends that cookie back to the server on each request, which PHP picks up and use that session id to access the session data on the server.

Comment: Do you have further code after the login block (after the `if (password_verify`... ) that could alter the session right after it is set ? Because i see no `exit` after the `header('Location: ...)` line, and any code after that may be executed unintentionally.

Comment: Thanks for the direction everyone. @ADyson When I use `echo 'Welcome, this is a successful login attempt for ' . $_SESSION['name'] ` the var_dump returns all the values. However when I replace the echo line with `header('Location: home.php');  ` to call the next page the var dump is empty despite calling the session.